# How to deny path containing dot dot slash(relative path) in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

My web application behind nginx should not receive any url which containing relative path such as `../`, it would be much safer to reject them directly at the Nginx level.

Tried this configuration but not working:

```
location ~ \.\.\/ {
  return 400;
}
```

with testing case:

```
printf "GET /web/../play/find.js HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\n\r\n" | nc 127.0.0.1 80
```

Comment: Your `location` rule will not work because `nginx` has already resolved any `..` path elements by then. You will need to check `$request_uri` using a `map` or `if` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith You are right!

Answer (score 2):

With the help from @RichardSmith, people could add this regular expression test before any location matching:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "\.\./"){
    return 403;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8095;
}
```

Comment: Nice, that's working